# Como retornar valor em uma função javascript

Tags: javascript, express.js

Estou estudando o framework `Express` para criar um serviço de `REST` e ao escrever uma`function` não estou conseguindo retornar o valor que foi processado.

Ao realizar a chamada para o endpoint `/test`, é executado o código abaixo:

```
 app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    const value = getNextSequenceValue('cursoId');
    console.log(value);
    res.json(value);
});
```

Então, a `function getNextSequenceValue` executa a logica abaixo:

```
function getNextSequenceValue(sequenceName)  {
    let returnNextValue = 0;
    MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, client) => {

    //defini o banco de dados como 'test'
    const db = client.db('test');

    //verificar se a coleção 'counters' existe no banco de dados 'test'
    //se não existir, cria a coleção 'counters' no banco de dados 'test'
    db.listCollections({ name: 'counters' }).toArray((err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            throw 'error in list collections';
        };
        if (result.length == 0) {
            db.createCollection('counters');
        };
    });

    //defini a coleção como 'counters'
    const collection = db.collection('counters');


    //verifica se na coleção 'counters' existe um documento com o 'id' igual a variavel 'sequenceName'
    //se não existir cria o documento, com o valor da sequenciaValue = 0
    collection.findOne({ id: sequenceName }).then(result => {
        if (!result) {
            collection.insertOne({
                id: sequenceName,
                sequenceValue: 0
            });
        };
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));


    //incremente a sequenciaValue em 1 do id passado.
    collection.findOneAndUpdate(
        { id: sequenceName },
        { $inc: { sequenceValue: 1 } },
        { 'returnNewDocument': true }
    )
    .then(result => {    
        console.log(result.value.sequenceValue);
        returnNextValue = result.value.sequenceValue;
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
    .finally(() => client.close());
});

return returnNextValue;
};
```

Como pode ser visto no trecho:

```
.then(result => {    
        console.log(result.value.sequenceValue);
        returnNextValue = result.value.sequenceValue;
    })
```

A saída no console está correta, a logica verifica as existências necessárias e exibe no console o valor da próxima sequencia.

Porém, não consigo atribuir esse valor a variável `returnNextValue`, logo o retorno esta sendo 0.

Comment: Já tentou deixar a função getNextSequenceValue como async e chamar ela com await na API do express?

Comment: não =/, vou pesquisar sobre isso. obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Olá, 
Eu já vi esse problemas antes, acho que é um problema de escopo de variável, talvez se usar `var` no lugar de `let`, vai funcionar, mas `var` está sendo eliminado dos códigos mais modernos. Abaixo segue uma solução, que espero vai funcionar.

Eu fiz alguns testes locais, com uma função mais simples do que a sua, e acho que o seguinte deve funcionar. caso não funcione, para que eu possa te ajudar, favor informar qual erro aparece na saída do console.

```
async function getNextSequenceValue(sequenceName)  {
    let returnNextValue = 0;
    MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, client) => {

    //defini o banco de dados como 'test'
    const db = client.db('test');

    //verificar se a coleção 'counters' existe no banco de dados 'test'
    //se não existir, cria a coleção 'counters' no banco de dados 'test'
    db.listCollections({ name: 'counters' }).toArray((err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            throw 'error in list collections';
        };
        if (result.length == 0) {
            db.createCollection('counters');
        };
    });

    //defini a coleção como 'counters'
    const collection = db.collection('counters');


    //verifica se na coleção 'counters' existe um documento com o 'id' igual a variavel 'sequenceName'
    //se não existir cria o documento, com o valor da sequenciaValue = 0
    collection.findOne({ id: sequenceName }).then(result => {
        if (!result) {
            collection.insertOne({
                id: sequenceName,
                sequenceValue: 0
            });
        };
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));


    //incremente a sequenciaValue em 1 do id passado.
    returnNextValue= await collection.findOneAndUpdate( //favor notar o await aqui, sem ele não funciona
        { id: sequenceName },
        { $inc: { sequenceValue: 1 } },
        { 'returnNewDocument': true }
    )
    .then(result => {    
        console.log(result.value.sequenceValue);
        return returnNextValue = result.value.sequenceValue;
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
    .finally(() => client.close());
});

return returnNextValue;
};
```

**Alternativa**

Como alternativa, baseado em comentário, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
 app.get('/test', async  (req, res) => {
    const value = await getNextSequenceValue('cursoId');
    console.log(value);
    res.json(value);
});
```

Mas não estou seguro que vai funcionar por que parece um problema de escopo de variável, se o `return returnNextValue` não receber o valor adequado, que seria a ideia da primeira proposta de solução, o valor nunca vai ser retornado corretamente.

Anexo:

usei o código abaixo para testar:

```
async function rockit() {
  let aux;

  await Kitten.find({ name: /^fluff/ }).then(() => {
    return (aux = 2);
  });

  console.log(aux);
}
```

Comment: Ao informar a clausula `await` é retornado o erro abaixo: `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

Comment: a função está definida como `async` ! como você está definindo e`async`ssa função? no mesmo arquivo? por algum motivo o compilador não está vendo o   `async`.

Comment: Voce notou que coloquei `async` no começo da palavra chave `function`? Pode ser isso.

Comment: Sim, notei, coloquei tbm, talvez seja por causa do framework `express`?

Comment: eu teste no express! além do mais isso é JavaScript, não depende do express

Comment: o erro que aparece é quando não se coloca `async `

Comment: No seu código, tente isso ` var returnNextValue = 0` no lugar de ` let returnNextValue = 0`. Em teoria a variável vai virar global.

Comment: @Thomas Erich Pimentel favor olha a atualização da resposta.

Comment: @Thomas Erich Pimentel  poderia tentar a nova resposta?

Comment: Olá @Thomas Erich Pimentel funcionou???

Comment: Jorge, agradeço a ajuda, porém, ao ler melhor a documentação do driver mongodb, verifiquei que o retorno do metodo `findOneAndUpdade` é uma `Promise` e então refatorei o código para trabalhar com esse tipo de retorno.

Comment: Sim, estava ciente, por isso precisa do `await` ! fico feliz que deu tudo certo no final!

Answer (score 0):

Poderia tentar essa solução também? testei localmente, com um problema mais simples.

```
 app.get('/test', async (req, res) => {//async garante o uso de await
    const value = await getNextSequenceValue('cursoId');//pede para esperar
    console.log(value);
    res.json(value);
});
```

e depois:

```
function getNextSequenceValue(sequenceName)  {
    let returnNextValue = 0;
    MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, client) => {

    //defini o banco de dados como 'test'
    const db = client.db('test');

    //verificar se a coleção 'counters' existe no banco de dados 'test'
    //se não existir, cria a coleção 'counters' no banco de dados 'test'
    db.listCollections({ name: 'counters' }).toArray((err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            throw 'error in list collections';
        };
        if (result.length == 0) {
            db.createCollection('counters');
        };
    });

    //defini a coleção como 'counters'
    const collection = db.collection('counters');


    //verifica se na coleção 'counters' existe um documento com o 'id' igual a variavel 'sequenceName'
    //se não existir cria o documento, com o valor da sequenciaValue = 0
    collection.findOne({ id: sequenceName }).then(result => {
        if (!result) {
            collection.insertOne({
                id: sequenceName,
                sequenceValue: 0
            });
        };
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));


    //incremente a sequenciaValue em 1 do id passado.
    return collection.findOneAndUpdate(//esse vai retorna para da função 
        { id: sequenceName },
        { $inc: { sequenceValue: 1 } },
        { 'returnNewDocument': true }
    )
    .then(result => {    
        console.log(result.value.sequenceValue);
        return result.value.sequenceValue;//esse vai retorna para fora do then
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
    .finally(() => client.close());
});

//return returnNextValue;
};
```

Favor reportar, caso apareça erros. Na função abaixo funciona:

```
rockit2();

async function rockit2() {
  console.log(await rockit());
}

function rockit() {
  let aux;

  return Kitten.findOneAndUpdate({ name: "fluffy" }, { name: "flu flu" }).then(
    () => {
      return 2;
    }
  );


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ao ler a documentação do driver node para MongoDb:

[Node.js MongoDB Driver API - findOneAndUpdate](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate)

Verificamos que o retorno é:

> Returns: Promise if no callback passed

Ou seja, o retorno é uma `Promise` portanto o retorno da `function getNextSequenceValue` também será uma `Promise` com isso, refatorei o código conforme abaixo:

Método GET:

```
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    getNextSequenceValue('cursoId').then(result => {
        res.json(result);
    }).catch(err => {
        res.json(err);
    });
});
```

Function

```
function getNextSequenceValue(sequenceName) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, client) => {
            const db = client.db('test');

            db.listCollections({ name: 'counters' }).toArray((err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    throw 'error in list collections';
                };
                if (result.length == 0) {
                    db.createCollection('counters');
                };
            });

            const collection = db.collection('counters');

            collection.findOne({ id: sequenceName }).then(result => {
                if (!result) {
                    collection.insertOne({
                        id: sequenceName,
                        sequenceValue: 0
                    });
                };
            }).catch(err => console.log(err));

            collection.findOneAndUpdate(
                { id: sequenceName },
                { $inc: { sequenceValue: 1 } },
                { 'returnNewDocument': true }
            ).then(result => {
                resolve(result.value.sequenceValue);
            }).catch(
                err => reject(err)
            ).finally(
                () => client.close()
            );
        });

    });
};
```